# Is there any Elliptic Curve algorithm equivalent to RSA's asymmetric encryption?

Tags: elliptic-curve

I've been searching but I cant find anything about this... only [EC Diffie-Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman) with symmetric cryptography, which is exactly what I do not want :(

Imagine this:

- generate a random private key, `k`
- then calculate a "public key" with ECC, `d=kG`

The algorithm I'm looking for is this: any message cyphered with the public key will "only" be decyphered by the owner of the private key.

Does this exists? Has anything like this been developed yet?

Comment: You can use elliptic curve El Gamal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try ecc (pip install ecc)

```
from ecc.Key.Key import Key

# Create keypair
k=Key.generate(521)

# Encode public key
pub=k.encode()

# Encode private key
priv=k.encode(include_private=True)

# Decode public key
pubK=Key.decode(pub)

# Decode private key
privK=Key.decode(priv)

# Encrypt message
msg=pubK.encrypt("Test")

# Decrypt message
print privK.decrypt(msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, El Gamal scheme, being based on Diffie–Hellman key exchange, presumes an asymmetric encryption algorithm, with private and public keys, so you should consider this. Computing the public key in this scheme will be as difficult as computing the discrete logarithm in the group.